# how to show snackbar message in flutter

Tags: android, sqlite, flutter, dart, snackbar

I am trying to show snackbar when user click the button but I can't do that.

I am not getting warning or error, I don't know what I am missing

here is my code:

```
RaisedButton(
   onPressed: () {
     if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
       formKey.currentState.save();
       dbHelper
         .addNote(Notes(categoryID, notBaslik,
              notIcerik, "", selectedOncelik))
         .then((savedNoteID) {
       if (savedNoteID != 0) {
         _scaffoldKey.currentState
             .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
         content: Text("Not Eklendi"),
         duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
         ));
        } else {}
        Navigator.pop(context);
       });
      }
     },
     child: Text("Kaydet"),
     color: Colors.red),
```

Comment: Can you confirm that savedNoteID is not 0?

Comment: @lrsvmb Yes I can, I add my record to db successfully

Comment: @TolgaKÜÇÜK What's the warning/error?

Comment: What is the error? Post your logcat and snackbar code where you write your snackbar

Comment: I mentioned on my question I do not get any message or warning

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that, that you define a Scaffold in your widget tree where you are trying to show the snackbar and that _scaffoldKey is added as property to your scaffold i.e.

```
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

Scaffold(key: _scaffoldKey, body: ...)
```

Alternatively you can use `Scaffold.of(context)`

```
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Not Eklendi"), duration: Duration(seconds: 2));
```

like:

```
RaisedButton(
   onPressed: () {
     if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
       formKey.currentState.save();
       dbHelper
         .addNote(Notes(categoryID, notBaslik,
              notIcerik, "", selectedOncelik))
         .then((savedNoteID) {
       if (savedNoteID != 0) {
         Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
         content: Text("Not Eklendi"),
         duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
         ));
        } else {}
        Navigator.pop(context);
       });
      }
     },
     child: Text("Kaydet"),
     color: Colors.red),
```

In some cases you will need to wrap it in a Builder widget to get the right `context`. You cab try that if still not working

Comment: I tried `Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar` also I defined _scaffoldKey and added my Scaffold tree but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a variable

```
final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

Add `_scaffoldKey`  to Scaffold

```
Scaffold(
key: _scaffoldKey,
)
```

**Code**

```
RaisedButton(
   onPressed: () {
     if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
       formKey.currentState.save();
       dbHelper
         .addNote(Notes(categoryID, notBaslik,
              notIcerik, "", selectedOncelik))
         .then((savedNoteID) {
       if (savedNoteID != 0) {
        final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text("Test"));
        _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
       
        } else {}
        Navigator.pop(context);
       });
      }
     },
     child: Text("Name"),
     color: Colors.red),
```